# Git Pull specific old commit and merge to the latest

Tags: git, github

One of my team member has merged 5 PRs in one go and it overwritten the some important code which was written a month ago.

Now I have the commit id of that particular code.

How can I pull changes of that particular commit id and include in the recent changes?

Note all the changes are in `develop` branch now. And that commit id also part of develop branch.

I want to include changes of that particular commit to recent changes of the `develop`.

Comment: `git cherry-pick`?

Comment: @matt I read about it through official docs, but I thought it was for 2 different branches. If I have to use for same branch what I need to do? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: A commit is not "part of" a branch. A branch is just a convenient name for _one_ commit. But you can cherry pick (or merge, or push) _any_ commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git cherry-pick <SHA1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) is a good option, provided that `<SHA1>` commit includes *all* the changes you want to restore.

If that commit simply reflects the code you want, but only add a missing ';' as a change, cherry-picking only that one commit won't help.

The alternative approach is to:

- reset HEAD of that old commit,
- carefully add all the changes made since that commit, fixing the overwritten code in the process

That is:

```
git switch -c tmp dev # where all 5 PR are merged
git reset --soft <SHA1> # old commit with correct code
git status
```

What the status show are all the files impacted by the subsequent commits: add them, fix the overwritten code and commit -in tmp branch).
Then

```
git switch dev
git merge tmp
```

Again, if your old commit actually have all the changes you want, cherry-pick is enough.
But if it does not, you can make a commit with all the right changes through the `git reset --soft` process mentioned above.